# Make div go underneath on small screen

Tags: html, css

I’m having a problem making my chatbox go underneath the video when the screen size get small. Also, how can I make the video not to get small on smaller screen?  I want it to be responsive.

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <!-- style="height: 90%; width: 60%; float:left;" height="100%" width="49%" align="left" -->
  <div class="youtube-video" id="video">
    <!-- for live video -->
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F1277805348996425%2Fvideos%2F<?php echo $liveID; ?>%2F&show_text=0&width=476" width="476" height="476" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
    <!-- <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F<?php echo $liveID; ?>%2Fvideos%2F1277978488979111%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" height="475" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe> -->
    <!-- <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F1277805348996425%2Fvideos%2F1278782988898661%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" height="475" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe> -->
    <!-- for embbedded facebook video (test purposes) -->
    <!-- <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDota2BestYolo%2Fvideos%2F<?php echo $liveID; ?>%2F&show_text=1&width=560" width="560" height="451" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe> -->

    <!-- youtube embed video -->
   <!-- <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCJaiEVEFaen5QC28rJp0fEw"></iframe> -->
  </div>

  <div class="chat row" >
    <div id="messages" class="chat-area"></div>
      <?php
            if (loggedin()) { ?>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <textarea style="padding: 10px;" rows="3" cols="50" class="entry row" placeholder="Type your message here..." name="msg" id="txtBox"></textarea>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <?php } else { ?>
                  <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="width: 400px;">
                      <textarea style="" id="message" rows="3" cols="50" class="entry row" placeholder="Type your message here..." name="msg"></textarea>

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Please Login</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>You must first login before you can join the conversation.</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="location.href='login.html'"/>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
             <?php } ?>
 </div> 

</div><!-- end of container -->
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHQG.png)
This is what I want to achieve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot06x.png)
But this is I am getting.

Comment: Can you provide working code...?

Comment: Sorry, it says that i cannot post 2 link. I'll update my comment. Sorry.

Comment: @Eyes-kun You can edit the question and include your html and CSS. You could also create a working snippet of your code using the `<>` icon in the edit menu.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TLprz89p This is a link to my css file. 

chat-are is the div for my chatbox and youtube-video for my video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-wrap` CSS property to get the job done. Apply flex-wrap property to the parent element that contains both Video and Chat elements.

Try checking out the demo on this page https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/ to see how it works. Resize your browser screen to see the yellow tiles wrap accordingly.

Comment: Where exactly do I need to put flex-wrap?

Comment: On the parent element that encloses your Video and Chat components.

Comment: Do I need to add class flex-item on my divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` to solve this. Use `flex-wrap: wrap` to get the chat on the bottom on a smaller screen and `flex-shrink: 0` to not let video reduce its size.

Run this snippet to understand.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.video {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.chat {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="video">
    VIDEO
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
    CHAT
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. My divs fit themselves into the center of the container when the screen gets smaller. Thanks, btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question assuming you are using Bootstrap 4 for your layout.
It is simple to use BS's responsive layouts. Here is the code you can try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Sample testing</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>Your chat component will come here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/h4Oza This is what I'm getting. I am missing the area where the messages will show.

Comment: You have to show me some code buddy. Else it is difficult to debug with a picture.